# Not Making a Mutable Copy for NSUserDefaults

Tags: objective-c, nsuserdefaults

Instead of making a mutable copy for NSUserDefaults, I use setObject: forKey: to make updates, pointing to constructed objects derived in various places in my UI.  Are there pitfalls to doing it this way?  Particularly, I want to make sure that I'm not adding new objects but am in fact replacing existing objects.

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There shouldn't be any problems doing things your way.

I'm not sure why you have this doubts, but as long as you use the same key `setObject:forKey` will of course update the same object instead of adding new ones. To avoid adding new object, I usually use a static `NSString` as the key.